# Filename without Extension in Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
for %%a in (.\*.jpg) do
```

The code above will store every jpg picture's name in %%a, but it stores the full name with the file extension, for example "Q.jpg".

I'm using a cmd utility for resizing images,

```
resize /width:100 %%a %%a.jpg
```

It will resize "Q.jpg" and then name it to "Q.jpg.jpg", as you can see the extension is now a part of file name!!!

I want to avoid it.

Comment: there are many expansions for filename parts  http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true i think you can use "%~n1"

Comment: If you have long filenames then use double quotes around the %%a as in `"%%a"` and `"%%~na.jpg"` etc.  You will probably find now that the source and target names are the same though, and could corrupt the source file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple, type for /? for more info:

To only get filename:

```
for %%a in (.\*.jpg) do resize /width:100 %%a %%~na.jpg
```

Quoting Windows batch help (type `for /?`):

> ```
> %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
> %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
> %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
> %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
> %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
> %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
> %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
> %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
> %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
> %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
> %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
>                environment variable and expands %I to the
>                fully qualified name of the first one found.
>                If the environment variable name is not
>                defined or the file is not found by the
>                search, then this modifier expands to the
>                empty string
> ```

The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

```
%~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
%~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
%~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
%~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH
               environment variable for %I and expands to the
               drive letter and path of the first one found.
%~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line
```

And that should help you with any further problems.